# running file diff on two files on Mac

Tags: diff

Im comparing to files, but my understanding is that `+` signifies addition and `-` symbols deletion. The new file has a typo:

```
if (KEY_STATUS.spacr) {
```

The why is it represented by `-`. It should be `+`, right ? When I run `diff -u game_new.js game_old.js`:

```
--- game_new.js 2018-06-12 02:03:32.000000000 -0700
+++ game_old.js 2018-06-12 02:03:22.000000000 -0700
@@ -4,9 +4,9 @@
 //

 KEY_CODES = {
-  13: 'enter',
   32: 'space',
   37: 'left',
+  38: 'up',
   39: 'right',
   40: 'down',
   70: 'f',
@@ -392,7 +392,7 @@
       this.vel.rot = 0;
     }

-    if (KEY_STATUS.spacr) {
+    if (KEY_STATUS.up) {
       var rad = ((this.rot-90) * Math.PI)/180;
       this.acc.x = 0.5 * Math.cos(rad);
       this.acc.y = 0.5 * Math.sin(rad);
@@ -406,7 +406,7 @@
     if (this.delayBeforeBullet > 0) {
       this.delayBeforeBullet -= delta;
     }
-    if (KEY_STATUS.enter) {
+    if (KEY_STATUS.space) {
       if (this.delayBeforeBullet <= 0) {
         this.delayBeforeBullet = 10;
         for (var i = 0; i < this.bullets.length; i++) {
@@ -919,7 +919,7 @@
     waiting: function () {
       Text.renderText(ipad ? 'Touch Sreen to Start' : 'Press Space to Start', 36, Game.canvasWidth/2 - 270, Game.canvasHeight/2);
       if (KEY_STATUS.space || window.gameStart) {
-        KEY_STATUS.space = false; // hack so we don't move right away
+        KEY_STATUS.space = false; // hack so we don't shoot right away
         window.gameStart = false;
         this.state = 'start';
       }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that when you run:

```
diff -u game_new.js game_old.js
```

The changes coming from the file on the *left* are interpreted as being the source, and marked with a minus, while the changes coming from the file on the *right* are treated as the destination, and marked with a plus.

If you want the `-` and `+` labels to appear as you want, then run `diff` with the files in the reverse order:

```
diff -u game_old.js game_new.js
```